# confusion regarding "id" in obj-c programming guide of Apple

Tags: objective-c, ios

**id**
In Objective-C, object identifiers are of a distinct data type: id. This type is the general type for any kind of object regardless of class and can be used for instances of a class and for class objects themselves.

```
id anObject;
```

Till here its simple and clear

---

For the object-oriented constructs of Objective-C, such as method return values, id replaces int as the default data type. (For strictly C constructs, such as function return values, int remains the default type.)

didn't understand what its talking about id replaces int? and in last inside brackets int remains the default value?

---

The keyword nil is defined as a null object, an id with a value of 0. id, nil, and the other basic types of Objective-C are defined in the header file objc/objc.h.

id is defined as pointer to an object data structure:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

the above is not a obj-c syntax what is it and what it is explaining?

---

Every object thus has an isa variable that tells it of what class it is an instance. Since the Class type is itself defined as a pointer:

```
￼typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

the isa variable is frequently referred to as the “isa pointer.”

also didn't understand this last para.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "the above is not a obj-c syntax what is it and what it is explaining?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the object-oriented constructs of Objective-C, such as method return values, id replaces int as the default data type. (For strictly C constructs, such as function return values, int remains the default type.)

Your book's just being a bit confusing here. All it's saying is that if you're working with objects and you don't want to get more specific, `id` is a good data type to use.

> id is defined as pointer to an object data structure:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

> the above is not a obj-c syntax what is it and what it is explaining?

That's the internal representation of an object. Your book is trying to show that an objective C object isn't magic: under the surface it's just a struct. The data type `id` is a pointer to such a struct.

> Every object thus has an isa variable that tells it of what class it is an instance. Since the Class type is itself defined as a pointer:
>
> `typedef struct objc_class *Class;`
>
> the isa variable is frequently referred to as the “isa pointer.”

In its internal data structure, each object has a pointer to another object that represents its class.

You don't need to know this stuff if you're just interested in programming in Objective-C (at least not while you're learning). It does come in handy if you're doing some advanced stuff, such as when you're interacting with the Objective-C runtime directly.

Answer (score 1):

> didn't understand what its talking about id replaces int?

Objective-C is a superset of C.

In C, a function must have a return value. If a return value is not specified, then a function returns `int` by default.

Objective-C overrides this default behaviour of C and returns `id` as a default value from any class method that doesn't specify its return value. But at the same time leaves the default behaviour for other (C-)functions the same (i.e. `int` is still the default return value for everything else)

Comment: hiii shaggy, thanks for the reply. I am asking about this typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;  ... what this snippet doing? its specified in the obj-c guide